# Error with veelo chapter style

Tags: sectioning, memoir, chapters

When using XeLaTeX on OS X 10.8, I have problems using `memoir` and the `veelo` chapter style.  The following code gives me the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \hspace {.8em}\resizebox 
                                    {!}{\beforechapskip }{\chapnumfont \thec... 
l.5 \chapter{This is chapter 1}
```

I have narrowed it down to the use of the `veelo` chapter style, but I don't really know where to go from there.

```
\documentclass[9pt, twoside, onecolumn]{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\chapterstyle{veelo}
\begin{document}
\chapter{This is chapter 1}
\section{A new section}
The hyperref should be \href{mailto:dummy@email.org}{dummy@email.org}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please add `\usepackage{graphicx}` to avoid the error. See section B.1.5 of the manual of `memoir`:

> If you use this style you will also need to use the `graphicx` package [CR99] because of the `\resizebox` macro. The veelo style works best for chapters that start on recto pages.